# How to send multi-row texts using Python Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, steam

In general, I am using telegram bot to check the status of my Steam accounts as well as the amount of hours spent playing.
Currently I am using  `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f)` command in which 
`f = str(nick[x]) + " || " + str(status[x]) + " || " + str(hours[x]) + "\n"`. I use for loop in order to send each account's details as shown  [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY8Gl.png)
Is there a way to send it as one message? Thanks!